# Ayuda implementando este código orientado a objetos?

Tags: java

Tengo este problema: Escribir un POO que muestre usando un metodo, lo siguiente: tu nombre,tu apellido y tu peso en kilos; y que muestre lo mismo pero con los datos de un amigo. Los datos deben ser ingresados por teclado y atraves de un metodo. El programa debe contener un metodo constructor que inicialice los atributos con los siguientes valores: el nombre y apellidos a cadena vacia, y el peso a cero.

Soy muy novato y no se que hacer, sobre todo tengo dudas con el metodo constructor y para ingresar datos a traves de un metodo esto es todo lo que llevo:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class Datos{

    String nombre;
    String apellido;
    long numCuenta;
    int peso;

    public Datos(String nombre,String apellido,long numCuenta,int peso){
        nombre="";
        apellido="";
        numCuenta=0;
        peso=0;
    }

    public String obNombre(String nombre){
        this.nombre=nombre;
        return nombre;
    }
    public String obApellido(String apellido)
}
```

Comment: a ver.. veamos.. que es obNombre? porque devuelve lo mismo que recibe como parametro? que sentido tiene? que es numCuenta? para que existe? como se leen datos de la consola? como se muestran datos en la consola? todo eso podes ir investigando...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Como necesitas setear valores en blanco en el constructor, debería ser así:

```
public Datos(){
    nombre="";
    apellido="";
    numCuenta=0;
    peso=0;
}
```

De esta manera cada que creas el objeto `Datos`, los valores iniciales son `""` y `0`.

```
Datos dato1 = new Datos();
Datos dato2 = new Datos();
```

Para mostrar los datos de cada objeto puedes tener este método:

```
public static void ShowDatos(Datos dato) {
    System.out.println(dato.peso);
}
```

Este método recibe el objeto de tipo `Datos` y puedes acceder a las variables de ese objeto.

Uniendo todo quedaría algo así:

```
public class Datos{

String nombre;
String apellido;
long numCuenta;
int peso;

public Datos(){
    nombre="";
    apellido="";
    numCuenta=0;
    peso=0;
}

public static void ShowDatos(Datos dato) {
    System.out.println(dato.peso); //4.Imprimiría 10
}

public static void main(String []args){
     Datos dato1 = new Datos(); // 1. Creas los objetos
     Datos dato2 = new Datos();

     dato1.peso = 10;//2. Asignas valores, estos valores lo recibirías por input.

     ShowDatos(dato1); //3. LLamas al método.
 }
}
```

Comment: Gracias ya me quedo claro

Answer (score 0):

El constructor podría ser así:

```
    public Datos(String nombre,String apellido,long numCuenta,int peso){
        nombre=nombre;
        apellido=apellido;
        numCuenta=numCuenta;
        peso=peso;
    }
```

Puede que no entiendas cómo funciona, así que es más comprensible llamar de con nombres distintos a los atributos del objeto y a las variables del constructor:

```
    public Datos(String nombre1, String apellido1, long Cuenta, int peso1){
        nombre=nombre1;
        apellido=apellido1;
        numCuenta=Cuenta;
        peso=peso1;
    }
```

Y además, para dejarlo más claro, puedes utilizar el puntero al propio objeto `this`, de esta forma:

```
    public Datos(String nomb, String apell, long Cuenta, int p){
        this.nombre=nom;
        this.apellido=apell;
        this.numCuenta=Cuenta;
        this.peso=p;
    }
```

Ahora, en tu caso, quieres inicializar los valores de los atributos del objeto de la misma forma, es decir, peso a 0 y los strings vacíos. Eso significa que el constructor no debería de tener varios de los parámetros de entrada que pusiste (los que están entre paréntesis en el constructor), sólo te falta el dato de número de cuenta, que es el que habrá que pasar por el parámetro de entrada (sobre todo porque el número de la cuenta intuyo que es el identificador del objeto, por tanto es muy necesario que el objeto tenga un número de cuenta determinado). Por tanto:

```
    public Datos(int idCuenta){
        this.nombre="";
        this.apellido="";
        this.numCuenta=idCuenta;
        this.peso=0;
    }
```

Comment: También me olvidé de comentar, ```public String obApellido(String apellido)``` le falta el ; al final. Pero a menos que el código tenga que hacer algo en específico, los getters y los setters (para obtener datos del objeto y para modificarlos, respectivamente) se pueden insertar automáticamente con alguna función del IDE. En el caso de netbeans mediante alt+ins y luego en la sección "getters and setters", como pone en este hilo: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21074402/generate-getters-and-setters-in-netbeans

Comment: El numero de cuenta funcionaria algo asi como el peso, tambien debe ser inicializado en 0 y debe ser introducido por teclado